# What is wrong with my xcode? No bold NSLog, and no auto-fill brackets?

Tags: xcode

This seems to have happened at some point this afternoon. First of all, my NSLog is no longer in bold. And secondly, when i put a 2nd close bracket on something, it doesn't add one to the start if there isn't already one there.

Another thing i've noticed is the boxes when you import a file have unticked themselves.

Any ideas?

Comment: Xcode does this at times.  To know what to do about it one would first need to know which version of Xcode, as Xcode 3.xx and Xcode 4.xx work entirely differently.

Comment: I assume you tried restarting system, as Xcode is not a stable IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's still compiling OK, then Xcode just got confused while indexing. Sometimes it gets stuck in that state. A few things to try:

1. Quit Xcode and launch it again.
2. Clean the build folder. Hold down the Option key, then choose the menu Product > Clean Build Folder....  Then rebuild everything.
3. Close your project, go to the Organizer, find your project in the Projects tab, and press the Delete button next to its Derived Data. Then reopen the project.

Comment: @Andrew So why are you neither up-voting nor excepting this answer?

Comment: I thought it had, i was just testing a few things to make sure. It turns out it didn't. I still have the problems.

Comment: XCode is just getting worse and worse in it's behaviour. It's becoming unusable. Pity I was forced to upgrade to this buggy unstable version. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself, the problem was that syntax coloring was set to C instead of Objective-C.

Click Editor->Syntax Coloring->Objective-C